# Post apocalyptic story

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, post-apocalyptic

I read this story when I was a kid and know it was a multi-book story. It was probably written in the late 70s or 80s. It started off in a small town with two kids in a theater getting setting the place up for a play when a war erupted outside. They were locked in and when they came up everything was changed. They wandered around together and fell in love trying to survive in the new world. If anyone can find the name of the books or the author it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you remember any names or places? As it is this is an awfully general description. Anything more specific might help jog memories.

Comment: Could you please add a more descriptive, and 'searchable' title.

Comment: I highly doubt it's "A Boy and His Dog" but it is a good series to read.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a story which comes to my mind:

- [**Fire brats**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fire_Brats) (1987) by Barbara Siegel, Scott Siegel and Barbara Steiner

> Firebrats is a series set in the aftermath of World War 3, it follows the struggles of two teenagers Matt and Dani to escape a nuclear-bombed city and find a new life.

Comment: hi just checked this on meta http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5066/when-answering-a-question-and-you-have-2-answers-should-you-post-2-or-1/5069#5069 and you should split this into 2 answers so if one is correct it can be marked as answer and there is no confusion which is the answer

Comment: @Dreamwalker But if there is no correct answer, there would be 2 wrong answer instead of one :)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with a wrong answer sometimes helps someone find something related they might like :)

Comment: @Dreamwalker Ok, done.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another story which comes to my mind:

- [**Brother in the Land**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brother_in_the_Land) (1984) by Rob Swindells

> It follows the adventures of Danny, a teenage boy as he fights for survival following a nuclear war.
>
> Danny not only has to cope in a world of lawlessness and gang warfare, but he has to protect and look after his little brother, Ben, and a girl called Kim